# Redux: How to compile action creators into one action creators sheet?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs

For each component I have action creators file called, `actions.js`. And in it for `ComponentOne`, I have:

```
let actions = {
  logSaying() {
    console.log("Hi there");
  }
}

export default actions
```

Then I have one main action creators file, and attempted to put all the actions together into one sheet like so:

```
import componentOneActions from './ComponentOne/actions'

let actions = {
  componentOneActions,
  //componentTwoActions,
  //etc.
}

export default actions
```

And would pass down the actions to all the components like so from the main action creators sheet:

```
import actions from './actions'

...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}
```

But none of the actions are being passed down when I tried `console.log()`. Why isn't it being passed down and how can I form one action creators sheet? And is there actually a better way of doing it?

Thank you in advance and will upvote/accept answer.

Comment: Are you importing `bindActionCreators` from `redux`?

Comment: how does you component look like and how are you logging the actions

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I just have a button that calls the actions, and for logging, I am simply doing `console.log()`

Comment: @RandomUser Yes I am

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Previous answer is wrong.

Perhaps you use `actions` in a wrong way.

From [document](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html), `bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)` accepts first param as `actionCreators`.

And `actionCreators` is an object like:

```
function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text
  }
}
```

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#action-creators

So your `actions` is not exactly `actionCreators`.

You should put `console.log()` in your reducer and make `actions` simple object as document shows.

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      console.log();
      return {}    
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-more-actions

Comment: I'm getting `ReferenceError: Objects is not defined()`

Comment: @JoKo Sorry for typing miss. is `Object.assign()`

Comment: No worries, and there is no bug anymore. But no actions are showing once console logged.

Answer (score 0):

isn't `componentOneActions` a list of functions? so you want to flatten them by using the `spread syntax`:

`let actions = {
  ...componentOneActions,
  //...componentTwoActions,
  //etc.
}`

do note, that using the same function name in One and Two will only give the last given function by that name

Answer (score 0):

`bindActionCreators()` expects a flat array of action functions to bind to. You're passing an object not an array. Try running `bindActionCreators` on each array of actions on the object.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  const keys = Object.keys(actions);
  const mappedActions = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      const key = keys[i];
      mappedActions[key] = bindActionCreators(actions[key], dispatch)
  }
  return {
    actions: mappedActions
  }
}
```